# Autoconf: Detect if emacs is installed

Tags: emacs, configure, autoconf, automake

What is the best way to detect if emacs is installed? The nesC compiler build (apparently) requires emacs to be installed, and I'd like to modify their configure script to detect this, but I don't know of any `AC_` macro to detect emacs...

What would be the best way to reliably detect this-- checking for /usr/bin/emacs? Checking the results of `which emacs` (assuming the system has `which`...)?

Relevant: https://github.com/tinyos/nesc/issues/1

Comment: Tell me this is a joke!  The compiler requires emacs?!  I wonder when will I be able to set `CC=emacs`?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Automake as well, you can use the `AM_PATH_LISPDIR` macro.  It takes the value of the `EMACS` environment variable if set, and otherwise looks for `emacs` or `xemacs` in the path.

```
AM_PATH_LISPDIR
AS_IF([test "$EMACS" = no], [AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find Emacs])])
```

It also tries to run emacs to determine where elisp files should be installed.  See [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Emacs-Lisp.html) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Use `AC_ARG_VAR` to expose the variable to the user (and list it in `./configure --help`) and `AC_PATH_PROGS` to check for emacs/xemacs. If you only want GNU emacs, use `AC_PATH_PROG([EMACS], [emacs], [no])` instead.

```
AC_ARG_VAR([EMACS], [Path to emacs.])
AS_IF([test -z "$EMACS"], [AC_PATH_PROGS([EMACS], [emacs], [no])])

# If you want to fail out if you can't find emacs:
AS_IF([test "$EMACS" = no],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR([emacs is required to build. Install it, or set $EMACS])])
```